# std::ranges zip view to iterate over two equal size ranges at the same time

Tags: c++, iteration, c++20

Since c++20 std::ranges doesn't have a zip view like [range-v3 does](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/zip.hpp), I am working on implementing a basic version of such a zip view to iterate over two ranges at the same time. The ranges should be equal in size. If they are not equal in size, the view should iterate over both ranges and stop as soon as one range has reached the end.

I would like feedback on whether this implementation is correct (iterator implementation, references, forwarding) and if it could be improved in any way.

Demo on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/r7Y8hfcd8

My Implementation:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<std::ranges::input_range Rng1, std::ranges::input_range Rng2>
    requires std::ranges::view<Rng1> && std::ranges::view<Rng2>
struct zip_view : std::ranges::view_interface<zip_view<Rng1, Rng2>>
{
    using reference = std::pair<
        std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng1>,
        std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng2>>;
    using const_reference = std::pair<
        std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng1>,
        std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng2>>;
    using value_type = std::pair<
        std::remove_cv_t<
            std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng1>>>,
        std::remove_cv_t<
            std::remove_reference_t<std::ranges::range_reference_t<Rng2>>>>;

    struct iterator;
    using const_iterator = iterator;

private:
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng1> m_rng1_begin, m_rng1_end;
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng2> m_rng2_begin, m_rng2_end;

public:
    zip_view() = default;
    zip_view(Rng1&& rng1, Rng2&& rng2)
        : m_rng1_begin(std::begin(rng1)),
          m_rng1_end(std::end(rng1)),
          m_rng2_begin(std::begin(rng2)),
          m_rng2_end(std::end(rng2))
    {
    }

    zip_view(Rng1 const& rng1, Rng2 const& rng2)
        : m_rng1_begin(std::begin(rng1)),
          m_rng1_end(std::end(rng1)),
          m_rng2_begin(std::begin(rng2)),
          m_rng2_end(std::end(rng2))
    {
    }

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(m_rng1_begin, m_rng2_begin); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(m_rng1_end, m_rng2_end); }

    const_iterator cbegin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(m_rng1_begin, m_rng2_begin);
    }
    const_iterator cend() const
    {
        return const_iterator(m_rng1_end, m_rng2_end);
    }
};

template<typename Rng1, typename Rng2>
zip_view(
    Rng1&& rng1, Rng2&& rng2
) -> zip_view<std::ranges::views::all_t<Rng1>, std::ranges::views::all_t<Rng2>>;

template<std::ranges::input_range Rng1, std::ranges::input_range Rng2>
    requires std::ranges::view<Rng1> && std::ranges::view<Rng2>
struct zip_view<Rng1, Rng2>::iterator
{
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = zip_view<Rng1, Rng2>::value_type;

private:
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng1> m_it1;
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng2> m_it2;

public:
    iterator() = default;
    iterator(
        std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng1> it1, std::ranges::iterator_t<Rng2> it2
    )
        : m_it1(std::move(it1)), m_it2(std::move(it2))
    {
    }

    iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++m_it1, ++m_it2;
        return (*this);
    }

    iterator operator++(int) { return ++iterator(m_it1, m_it2); }

    bool operator==(iterator const& other) const
    {
        // check if one of the iterators is equal so we don't iterate past the
        // end in case (m_it1 == end) and (m_it2 != end) or (m_it1 != end) and
        // (m_it2 == end)
        return (m_it1 == other.m_it1) || (m_it2 == other.m_it2);
    }

    bool operator!=(iterator const& other) const
    {
        // check if both of the iterators are unqequal so we don't iterate past
        // the end in case (m_it1 == end) and (m_it2 != end) or (m_it1 != end)
        // and (m_it2 == end)
        return (m_it1 != other.m_it1) && (m_it2 != other.m_it2);
    }

    reference operator*() { return reference(*m_it1, *m_it2); }

    const_reference operator*() const
    {
        return const_reference(*m_it1, *m_it2);
    }

    reference operator->() { return reference(*m_it1, *m_it2); }

    const_reference operator->() const { return reference(*m_it1, *m_it2); }
};

static_assert((bool)std::input_iterator<zip_view<
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>,
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>>::iterator>);

static_assert((bool)std::ranges::input_range<zip_view<
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>,
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>>>);

static_assert((bool)std::ranges::view<zip_view<
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>,
                  std::views::all_t<std::vector<int>>>>);
```

Example Usage:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    std::vector<std::string> v2({ "a", "b", "c", "d" });

    for (auto&& [a, b] : zip_view(v1, v2))
        std::cout << a << " : " << b << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We really can't tell whether an implementation is correct or not, that requires testing. We are happy to review the code and see if there are any improvements are possible if thee code is working as intended.

Comment: If C++23 is available to you, then a [zip_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) is available.  You probably want to ensure your class uses the same interface, to allow a smooth switchover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem with returning a pair of references

It looks like you have a `const_iterator` which when dereferenced returns a `const_reference`, which sounds like it should be a pair of `const` references, but it isn't. And even if `const` pair of references is deduced somewhere, that is not the same as a pair of `const` references. So you can write this code:

```
const auto const_zipped_view = zip_view(v1, v2);

for (const auto& [a, b] : const_zipped_view) {
    a = -1;
    b = "oops!";
}

for (auto&& [a, b] : zip_view(v1, v2))
    std::cout << a << " : " << b << "\n";
```

And it will compile without any warnings and print "-1 : oops!" a few times. Only if `v1` and/or `v2` themselves are `const` will a pair of `const` references be deduced.

C++23 introduces [`std::ranges::range_const_reference_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iterator_t), which might help create your `const_reference`, or you have to do it yourself [somehow](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/07/13/the-incredible-const-reference-that-isnt-const/).

This also makes it clear you need a lot more unit tests to verify that all the assumptions you might have about your zipped view are actually correct.

## Implement a real `const_iterator`

Your `const_iterator` is just the same as `iterator`, so if someone is explicitly calling `cbegin()` and `cend()` on a `zip_view`, they will still get a regular iterator that can potentially mutate the contents of the view.

## About the constructor

I am uncertain what the proper way would be to write the constructor for a `zip_view` classes. However, I fail to see why you have one overload take rvalue-references, when you are not going to `std::move()` them. Just take them by lvalue-reference.

## You can omit `operator!=()`

If you omit `operator!=()`, the compiler will generate a defaulted one that just calls `operator==()` and negates it, which is exactly what you want.

## Make the iterator more flexible

Your iterator only implements the bare minimum to be an input iterator. So it can only iterator over the view once, cannot iterate backwards, and cannot be used to have random access to the view, even if the two ranges do support all that.

One use case for allowing random access would be to be able to sort one array based on the contents of another, by writing something like:

```
std::vector<Key> keys = {…};
std::vector<Value> values = {…};
std::ranges:sort(zip_view(keys, values), {}, [](auto& kvp){return kvp.first;});
```

Of course, this will require a lot more effort to implement.

## Allow zipping more than two ranges at a time

It would be a nice exercise to create a `zip_view` that can handle three or more ranges at a time. This requires making it a variadic template, using `std::tuple` instead of `std::pair`, and parameter pack expansions. However, it will not require more lines of code than you already have.